# Justification for the definition of equivariant curvature

Tags: characteristic-classes, equivariant-cohomology

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group which act on a smooth manifold $M$.

Let $\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{g}] \otimes \mathcal{A}$ be the algebra of polynomial maps from $\mathfrak{g}$ to $\mathcal{A}(M),$ we define the equivariant exterior differential $d_\mathfrak{g}$ on it by the formula $$ (d_\mathfrak{g} \alpha)(X) = d(\alpha(X))- \iota(X)(\alpha(X)), X \in \mathfrak{g}.$$

If $E$ is a $G$-equivariant vector bundle, the space of equivariant differential forms with values in $E$  is the space $$ \mathcal{A}_G (M,E) = {(\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{g}] \otimes \mathcal{A}(M,E))}^G.$$

The following paragraph is from the book "Heat kernels and Dirac operators".

> Definition: The equivariant superconnection $\mathbf{A}_{\mathfrak{g}}$ corresponding to a $G$-invariant superconnection $\mathbf{A}$ is the operator on $\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{g}] \otimes \mathcal{A}(M,E)$ defined by the formula $$(\mathbf{A}_{\mathfrak{g}} \alpha)(X) = (\mathbf{A} - \iota(X))(\alpha(X)), X \in \mathfrak{g}.$$
> The justification for this definition is that $$\mathbf{A}_{\mathfrak{g}}(\alpha \wedge \theta) = d_{\mathfrak{g}}\alpha \wedge \theta + {(-1)}^{|\alpha|} \alpha \wedge \mathbf{A}_{\mathfrak{g}} \theta$$
> for all $alpha \in\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{g}] \otimes \mathcal{A}(M) $ and $ \theta \in \mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{g}] \otimes \mathcal{A}(M,E). $ The operator $\mathbf{A}_{\mathfrak{g}} $ preserves the subspace $\mathcal{A}_G(M,E)$, and we will also its restriction to this space by $\mathbf{A}_{\mathfrak{g}}$
> Bearing in mind the formula
> $$d^2_{\mathfrak{g}} \alpha(X) + \mathcal{L}(X) \alpha(X) = 0,$$
> We are motivated to define the equivariant curvature $F_\mathfrak{g}$ of the equivariant superconnection $\mathbf{A}_{\mathfrak{g}}$ by the formula
> $$ \epsilon((F_\mathfrak{g}(X))= {\mathbf{A}_{\mathfrak{g}}(X)}^2 + \mathcal{L}(X).$$

I didn't understand the argument of the author in the reason of defining the equivariant curvature in that way.

In the article: Seiberg-Witten Theory and equivariant localization of instantons, the author  says that

> The definition of equivariant curvature cannot be just $d^2_{Aeq}$ as in the non equivariant case as a simple example shows. Let $E = M × \mathbb{C}^n$ be the trivial vector bundle of rank $n$ and take $d_A=d$ be the standard de Rham operator . Then by definition $d_{A eq} =d_{eq}$ and ${(d_{A eq})}^2= d^2_{eq} = -(d\iota_X + \iota_X d) = - \mathcal{L}_X.$

Your help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.